# Creating String Arrays and passing each index value to a variable after a given period

Tags: string, array

Is there a way to take an input string, store it into a array and then pass each index of that array to a variable to hold  before being overwritten by the next array index value?

For example:

A number of input values which are of type:String are being created

```
String 1 is given as "Value: 7.93 22-10-2017 10:33:32"
String 2  is given as "Value: 8.93 22-10-2017 12:10:15"
.
.
.
String 10  is given as "Value: 6.93 22-10-2017 18:03:04"
```

The string structure is known but its contents as such will vary

After a time period of say 60sec. The contents of array[0] which will be String 1 will be assigned to a given variable "output"

After the next 60sec time period .The contents of array[1]  Which will be String 2 will be stored into  the same "Output" variable in which the previous value will be now overwritten

This continues until array[9] i.e String 10 in which the array will begin over and start to populate "output" with newly presented string values

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Also, please tell us what you are trying to achieve. Passing an index to a variable is not the real goal, but only the means to an end. What is your real goal?

Comment: Originally I was attempting to pass the characters of each string using the toCharArray() function. The solution was much simpler and straight forward in the end. I've posted it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Used Below:

```
// Input 1-3 represents input string

String Input1 ="Value: 7.93 22-10-2017 10:33:32";
String Input2 ="Value: 8.93 22-10-2017 12:10:15";
String Input3 ="Value: 8.93 22-10-2017 12:10:15";
String message[] ={Input1,Input2,Input3};

// Assigned 'Output' Variable will be populated by each index of the array
String Output;

  void setup()
   {
        Serial.begin(9600);
   }


// Each index of the array will be stepped through and passed to 'Output'
//delay() will control period between each index value

void loop()
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                  Output=message[i];
                  Serial.println(Output);
                  delay(5000);
            }

     }
```